# How to get a series of random points in a specific range of distances from a reference point and generate xyz coordinates

Tags: python

I have to generate a various points and its xyz coordinates and then calculate the distance.
     Lets say I want create random point coordinates from point a away from 2.5 cm in all directions. so that i can calculate the mutual distance and angles form a to all generated point (red)
I want to remove the redundant point and all those points which do not satisfy my criteria and also have same position.

![enter image description here][1]

for example, I know the coordinates for the two points *a* (-10, 12, 2) and *b* (-9, 11, 5).      The distance between *a* and *b* is 5 cm.
The question is: How can I generate the red points' coordinates.     I knew how to calculate the distance and angle.    So far, I have tried the following calculation:

I am not able to define the points randomly.
I found a few solutions that don't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Try also to rephrase your question, since it is really vague.

Comment: Where do you want the red points to be? It is not obvious from your picture or your description. You only say you "don't want them randomly" but where do you want them?

Comment: I rephrase the question. I knew how to calculate the distance and angle. but i am not able to generate points coordinate and how to remove the redundant points.

Comment: For a 2D surface, think about an equation for a circle drawn with a radius 2.5 cm from centerpoint A, and then sampling coordinates randomly that solve that circle's equation. For 3D, you'd use a sphere, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to define the point pseudo randomly you can use [random.randrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

```
from random import randrange as rd
from math import sqrt
ptBlu=[11,12,13] #example of blu point
ptRedx=ptBlu[0]+rd(-10,10,1) #x coordinate of a red point(rd is the function stand for random.randrange)
ptRedy=ptBlu[1]+rd(-10,10,1) #y coordinate of a red point
ptRedz=ptBlu[2]+rd(-10,10,1) #z coordinate of a red point
ptRed=[ptRedx,ptRedy,ptRedz] #list with the x,y,z coordinates
```

If you want to create a series of points with a distance greater than a certain one from a certain point avoiding to create points with the same coordinates. You have to do something more elaborate. This is the example for a 2D plane as your draw. For a 3D example simply add the third coordinate and adjust the formulae.

```
redptlist=[] #inizialize a void lists for red point coordinates
xredptlist=[] 
yredptlist=[]
pointcounter=0 #initizlize counter for the while loop
mindist=2.5#set the minimum euclidean distance beyond you want to create the points
maxdist=12#set the maximum euclidean distance redpoint can have from blu point
maxc=int(sqrt((maxdist**2)/2)) #from the euclidean distance formula you can get the max      coordinate
while True: #create a potentailly infinite loop! pay attention!
     if pointcounter<20: #set the number of point you want to add (in this case 20)
         x_RedPtshift=rd(-maxc,maxc,1) #x shift of a red point 
         y_RedPtshift=rd(-maxc,maxc,1) #y shift of a red point
         if sqrt(x_RedPtshift**2+y_RedPtshift**2)>mindist: #if the point create go beyond the minimum distance
             ptRedx=ptBlu[0]+ x_RedPtshift#x coordinate of a red point
             ptRedy=ptBlu[1]+ y_RedPtshift #y coordinate of a red point
             ptRed=[ptRedx,ptRedy] #list with the x,y,z coordinates
             if ptRed not in redptlist: #avoid to create red point with the same coordinates
                 redptlist.append(ptRed) # add to a list with this notation [x1,y1],[x2,y2]
                 xredptlist.append(ptRedx) # add to a list with this notation [x1,x2,x3...] for plotting
                 yredptlist.append(ptRedy) # add to a list with this notation [y1,y2,y3...] for plotting
                 pointcounter+=1 #add one to the counter of how many points you have in your list 
     else: #when pointcounter reach the number of points you want the while cicle ends
         break
```

Try to test it with [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(ptBlu[0],ptBlu[1],'bo')#plot blu point
plt.plot(xredptlist, yredptlist, 'ro')#plot red points
minCircle=plt.Circle((ptBlu[0],ptBlu[1],1),mindist,color='b',fill=False)#draw circle with min distance
maxCircle=plt.Circle((ptBlu[0],ptBlu[1],1),maxdist,color='r',fill=False)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(minCircle)
fig.gca().add_artist(maxCircle)
plt.axis([-3, 25, -1, 25])
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:
[image: plotting result]

Comment: thank GM. its working. But if i want to generate point from a point away from 2.5 cm in all direction. 
how to do that.

Comment: I've improved the answer. I suggest you to change the title in something like: _How to get a series of random points in a specific range of distances from a reference point_ or something like that maybe you'll have more answers.

Comment: Thanks GM. That exactly i wanted. What you have done in your answers. The second ans is not working. I am trying to figure out.

Comment: when i run this script on a command line its working. but as script it shows error. 
rd = random.randrange
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randrange'

Comment: Ok, try it now. For the [tag:random] error I think you have some other files named random in your current directory or in the python path. Search for the fake _random.py_ and delete it. If you want to find all the path where it can be type 'import sys' and then type 'sys.path' in your shell.

Comment: okk
can this script also generate random point inside the sphere??
thanks GM for your cooperation and great help.

Comment: Of course, you simply have to add the third coordinate and re-arrange the formulae. For the matplotlib part you have to do more thing to have a 3D image. You're welcome best wishes for your studies!

Answer (score 1):

Generically you can  populate your points in two ways:

1) use random to create the coordinates for your points within the outer bounds of the solution. If a given random point falls outside the max or inside the inner limit.

2) You can do it using polar coordinates: generate a random distance between the inner and outer bound and a yaw rotation. In 3d, you'd have to use two rotations,  one for yaw and another for pitch. This avoids the need for rejecting points.

You can simplify the code for both by generating all the points in a circle (or sphere) around origin (0,0,0) instead of in place.  Them move the whole set of points to the correct blue circle location by adding it's position to the position of each point.